# Java Strings object in ArrayList

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, collections

In my MainActivity I have this lines of code:

```
    //data.getFirstUserInput()-1 is equal to user input.
     deck.setCardNumberEmpty(data.getFirstUserInput()-1);

       System.out.println("\n Cards on table");
                 ArrayList<Deck> deck= deck.getCards();
                  Collections.sort(cards);
                  for (Deckc: deck
           System.out.print((format("%10s","\033[F[ " + c.getOneSpecificNumber())+ " ]"));}
```

This prints out my random card numbers. But the problem is they are not numerically sorted,

Any idea what I can do?

**Card Class**

```
public class Card {

    private String cardLetter;
    private String cardNumber;
    private String nullValue;

    public Card(String cardLetter, String cardNumber, String nullValue){
        this.cardLetter = cardLetter;
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.nullValue = nullValue;
    }

  public String getOneSpecificNumber() { return cardNumber;}
  public void setCardNumber(String x){  cardNumber = x;  }


private ArrayList<Deck> deck = new ArrayList();
public Deck(){
                   char A  = 'A';
    int repeats = 2, numOfCards = 8;
    for ( int i = 0; i<numOfCards;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<repeats; j++){
            cards.add(new Card((char) ( A + i ) + "",i+1,""));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to sort the `cards` Array as per the `cardNumber` your `Card` class has to implement the `Comparable` and override `compareTo()`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    private String cardLetter;
    private String cardNumber;
    private String nullValue;

    public Card(String cardLetter, String cardNumber, String nullValue){
        this.cardLetter = cardLetter;
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.nullValue = nullValue;
    }

    public int compareTo(Card c) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(this.cardNumber) || 
           StringUtils.isEmpty(c.cardNumber)) return -1;
        return Integer.parseInt(this.cardNumber) - Integer.parseInt(c.cardNumber);
    }

    public String getOneSpecificNumber() { return cardNumber; }

    public void setCardNumber(String x) {  cardNumber = x; }
}
```

`StringUtils` is part of Apache Commons Lang3, if you do not want to include it in your project then you can do something like this:

```
if(null == this.cardNumber || "".equals(this.cardNumber) ||
       null == c.cardNumber || "".equals(c.cardNumber)) return -1;
```

Now you just have to do this in order to sort:

```
Collections.sort(cards);
```

Example:

```
System.out.println("\n Cards on table");
List<Card> cards = deck.getCards();
Collections.sort(cards);
for (Card c: cards) {
    System.out.print((format("%10s","\033[F[ " + c.getOneSpecificNumber())+ " ]"));
}
```

Comment: public int compareTo(Card c){
            return this.cardNumber - c.cardNumber;
        }    

I'm not sure what this piece of code does, but It gives me an error.
"Bad operand types for binary operator'-'
first type: String
second type: String

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
Any idea why I could get this error?

Tried ovveride the annotation but It's the same problem

Comment: @user3506 You have `null` or blank values in `cardNumber`. Add a check to prevent exception. I have updated the answer using the `StringUtils`. Decide the return order appropriately in such cases.

Comment: I guess your last updated answer is the check right?
Or am I suppose to add an nullPointerException in order to prevent following error for the isEmpty method?
"Cannot find symbol"
"Symbol"method isEmpty(String)"
"location class StringUtils"

Comment: @user3506 Yes, the updated answer includes the check. If you want to use `StringUtils` then you'll have to include the Apache Commons Lang3 JAR: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4 Alternatively you can do something like this: `if(null == this.cardNumber || "".equals(this.cardNumber))`

Comment: Sorry, but still the same error, when using  
@Override
        public int compareTo(Card c) {
        if(null == this.cardNumber || "".equals(this.cardNumber)) return 1;{ 
       return Integer.parseInt(this.cardNumber) - Integer.parseInt(c.cardNumber);
        }
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
The code lines that causes the error are apparently: 
     return Integer.parseInt(this.cardNumber) - Integer.parseInt(c.cardNumber);

So I thought it was caused beacuse of the first return value, But removing return 1; didn't help...

Comment: @user3506 That is because you are only checking `this.cardNumber`. What about `c.cardNumber`? It can also be blank or `null`. Check the updated answer, I have added a note in case you don't want to use `StringUtils`. It has the full check.

Comment: @user3506 In summary, you'll have to do this: `if(null == this.cardNumber || "".equals(this.cardNumber) ||
       null == c.cardNumber || "".equals(c.cardNumber)) return -1;`

Comment: Oh I see that I missed something in the code snippet you updated.
It works great now thank you so much!

Comment: @user3506 Your Welcome! Please accept the answer by clicking the greyed-out tick mark just below the voting counter if you are happy with the solution.

Comment: Accepted :) Thank you @user2004685 !

Comment: @user3506 Your Welcome! :)